# Does MonoDevelop's syntax deviate from VisualStudio's

Tags: mono, monodevelop, c#, syntax

I'm an IT student and we started learning C# this semester, we are working with VisualStudio 2012 in class. Since I installed ubuntu recently I do not know much about anything, but I like it very much.

My question is does the syntax in MonoDevelop differ much from the one in VisualStudio, because VisualStudio uses .NET framework, but ubuntu probably uses something else, and can I/should I use ubuntu for writing programs in it, or should I just use VisualStudio on windows (haven't dual booted my laptop yet, but have win10 on PC).

Answer (score 0):

Mono on Ubuntu is almost the same as .NET in MS Windows. The differences are when you want Windows API functions which are not existing in Ubuntu. Otherwise it should work. Microsoft supports Mono development. I guess you can always encounter some functionalities that will not work in mono but in general there should be no problem. Be careful not to use Win API and you should be fine.

I was developing some programs with MonoDevelop using C# and mono and when I created an exe file it worked unchanged in Windows and vice versa. Even remoting and inter process communication worked out of the box.

Read this: http://www.mono-project.com/docs/faq/general/#mono-and-microsoft

Comment: To clarify: Mono does not contain Windows-specific libraries, including Windows Forms and WPF. Depending on the course, it's certainly possible those will be taught.